# How to create cluster index in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I search many links on google to find out how to create cluster index in oracle but none were satisfactory in explaining. Can anybody please explain how to achieve this in oracle.

Comment: `INDEX ORGANISED TABLE`?  That might be Oracle's closest equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An equivalent to a SQL Server Cluster Index in Oracle would be an Index Organized Table.
Here is some info: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index